# No match for call to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In my class I'm trying to create unsigned 2d vector and then initialize it in constructor after getting its size. Here is my class:

```
class RobotWorld {
    private:
    int n;
    vector <vector<int>> v;
    public:
    RobotWorld (int n){
        n = n;

        v(n, vector<int>(n, n));
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            v[i][0] = i;
        }
    }
};
```

When I do it like this, I get an error: No match for call to std::vector.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code and how I can improve it.

Comment: I need a two dimensional array with n vectors and n elements(integers) in each vector

Comment: how it is better to initialize it? I've been using constructor from cppreference but probably I misunderstood it.

Comment: It was intended to create twodimensional vector with n vectors and n elements in each vector

Comment: As a side note, avoid giving the input parameter the same name of your class members. It's confusing and may create bugs.

Comment: Side note: if you want a regular 2D array, it's usually better to have one `vector` of size `rows * cols` and do the indexing into it yourself; it's easier to work with and more cache-firendly. `vector<vector>` makes sense mainly if the inner vectors are not all of the same size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close.  When constructing a class all of the members all initialized in the member initializer list.  This is where your initialization needs to be.  When you do it in the constructor body, doing `variable_name(stuff)` tries to call the function call operator and not the constructor.  This is why you get the compiler error since `vector` has no such operator.  We can change the code to

```
RobotWorld (int n) : n(n), v(n, vector<int>(n, n)){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        v[i][0] = i;
    }
}
```

And now both `n` and `v` get properly initialized and then you manipulate the vector.

Comment: _"When you do it in the constructor body you are trying to construct something that has already been constructed."_ Worse, he wasn't trying to construct anything, but instead to invoke a non-existent function call operator on the vector.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated.